# Imagick Class not loading

Tags: php, apache, mamp, darwin

I followed an online tutorial to install ImageMagick and then PECL Imagick Class. I correctly followed all the steps, and added the `extension=imagick.so` to **php.ini**, but it keeps throwing the following error: `Class 'Imagick' not found in...`. Then, if I execute `phpinfo()` I don't get any *Imagick* section. What can I do?

```
PHP Version: 5.4.10
System: Darwin server.local 12.3.0 (MAMP)
Darwin Kernel Version 12.3.0: Sun Jan 6 22:37:10 PST 2013;
root:xnu-2050.22.13~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

Build Date: Jan 21 2013 15:11:11
```

Edit: I already modified **php.ini** (the correct one, shown in `phpinfo()`) and restarted the server several times.

Comment: did you modify the good `php.ini` (you can have multiple `php.ini` depend on your installation/configuration. Did you reboot the PHP server ? Show us the part of your `php.ini`

Comment: I already modified php.ini (the correct one, shown in phpinfo()) and restarted the server several times.

Comment: So now, in phpinfo() you have the ImageMagik loaded ?

Comment: What is the version of your PHP ?

Comment: @MatRt nope, it's not loaded (but I can access it via terminal). The PHP version (as I said in the post) is 5.4.10

Comment: And what is the version of ImageMagik ? You can also check the PHP load because if the .so is not loaded, maybe there are some info in the log/error file

Comment: I'd greatly benefit from an answer. I've, too, stumbled upon this problem. Had a long night and no success whatsoever.